# How does Django know what 'pk' to use in urls.py?

Tags: python, django

I've been learning Django over the past couple of weeks, and there is one thing that really seems to confuse me. Which model's attributes does Django use to define the `<pk>` that is used in `urls.py`?

For example, If I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name="product-detail"),
]
```

I had assumed previously that the `pk` would be derived from the model instance that is being used in the given view, in this case, `ProductDetailView.as_view()`. However, I'm starting to question that logic as you can pass multiple models into a view, of course.

### **Part 2**

Also, what if I wanted to use the `pk` of one model instance, while *only* using a **different** model instance in the view?

For example, what if I had two models, `Products` & `Stores` which both hold a many-to-many relationship (eg. a product could be in multiple stores, and a store can hold many products). Then I wanted to have a `url` where I have a `StoreListView` listing all the stores that hold a given product, so my url would be something like:

`url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', StoreListView.as_view(), name="store-list")`

*Where the `pk` is of the `Product` instance but the `view` is of the `Store` instance*

To finalize the question, again, how does Django define `pk`?

Comment: It relies on the `model` attribute of your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the various methods and attributes of the detail view here, particularly the get_object method:

http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    """
    Returns the object the view is displaying.
    By default this requires `self.queryset` and a `pk` or `slug` argument
    in the URLconf, but subclasses can override this to return any object.
    """
    # Use a custom queryset if provided; this is required for subclasses
    # like DateDetailView
    if queryset is None:
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
    # Next, try looking up by primary key.
    pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
    slug = self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg)
    if pk is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)

    # Next, try looking up by slug.
    if slug is not None and (pk is None or self.query_pk_and_slug):
        slug_field = self.get_slug_field()
        queryset = queryset.filter(**{slug_field: slug})
    # If none of those are defined, it's an error.
    if pk is None and slug is None:
        raise AttributeError("Generic detail view %s must be called with "
                         "either an object pk or a slug."
                         % self.__class__.__name__)
    try:
        # Get the single item from the filtered queryset
        obj = queryset.get()
    except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404(_("No %(verbose_name)s found matching the query") %
                  {'verbose_name': queryset.model._meta.verbose_name})

    return obj
```

It's Django, so its fairly customizable, so it doesn't need to be called 'PK'. You could override that by using the pk_url_kwarg. By default the id field is the pk, unless you specify it in your model definition.

Comment: That method isn't part of the `DetailView` its part of the mixin that `DetailView` implements.

Comment: Yes I know, but it isn't a method of the `DetailView`.

Comment: Does that really add anything to the discussion? It just sounds pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't define anything. You define it. ProductDetailView *must* have a `model` attribute; it is that attribute that defines what model to use.

Unfortunately, part 2 of your question doesn't really make sense; a view is not an instance of a model.

Comment: I understand the ProductDetailView must have a model attribute, that's not what I am asking though. I'm asking if `pk` comes from the model set in the view, which it sounds like it does. As for Part 2, if what I assume I said is right in the first part, then what happens if you switch models later down the line. A list view, in a way, is a list of many instances, so I'm asking if you go from one model at `products/<pk>` to `products/<pk>/stores`, which model does it use? In hind sight, lets say `products/<pk>/stores` is a detail view.

Comment: That's actually not entirely accurate; [Django will define the pk](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#the-pk-property) if you let it

Comment: I'm trying to understand your confusion, but failing. Each view is responsible for itself and has no relation to anything else. Since the view at .../stores is a DetailView, it will have its own `model` attribute and will use that.

Comment: @Hamms that doesn't appear to have anything to do with the OP's question or my answer.

Comment: So the <`pk`> in the url will be the `pk` of the `Product` instance, not from `Store` model? What if I wanted to do something like (I know this won't work but just for illustration):  `products/(?P<product.pk>\d+)/stores/(?P<store.pk>\d+)`?

Comment: No, it depends on the model attribute of the DetailView that's assigned to the .../store URL. If that's Store, it'll use a Store, if it's Product it'll use a Product. If you want to do what you describe, you'd need to define a custom `get_object` method on your view that looks up a Product and then finds the relevant Store in its M2M relation.

Comment: I think that your confusion may stem from thinking that somehow DetailView is fundamental to the way Django works, when really it's just a specific class that does a specific thing when configured in a specific way. Most views are not DetailViews; and the base DetailView just defines a `get_object` method that uses the `model` attribute to look up a particular model by pk; that's all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman OK... So let's say I'm looking at a ProductDetail View where Product.pk == 1 @ `...products/1 and then I click on some line to look at a StoreDetail View where Store.pk == 3, so will `products/1/store/3` still work as intended? I understand you would probably just go to `store/3`, but just to understand the concept.

Comment: I understand that the `DetailView` is not fundamental, just using it for illustration because it's simple.

Comment: I can't answer that because *it depends entirely on the implementation of StoreDetail*.

Answer (score 0):

Django's [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) uses the `SingleObjectMixin` mixin which has a method called [`get_object`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L35) which will look for a `pk_url_kwarg`

```
 pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
```

By default this is set to [`'pk'`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L19)